# Когда нужен JBoss сервер?

Tags: java

Я страстный поклонник языка `Java`, но кроме `tomcat`-a ничего другого как веб сервер не использовал, не приходилось. Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем прелести `JBoss`, `Websphere`, `EJB` и т.д., по сравнению с теми же `Spring,` `Hibernate` и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на ваши вопросы заслуживает если не отдельной книги, то большой статьи.

Следует прочесть всякие статьи и обсуждения из разряда [EJB vs Spring](http://www.google.ru/search?q=EJB+vs+Spring&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.mandriva:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox).

Основное функциональное отличие в том, что EJB позволяет выполнять удалённые вызовы по сети. Т.е. позволяет строить распределённые системы. Для этого предусмотрено несколько типов таких EJB-бинов. Для нормальной работы EJB нужен EJB-контейнер. Tomcat не содержит в себе такого. Для этого надо как минимум Glassfish. Часто используют для этой цели и JBoss.

Hibernate - это JPA-технология, которая никак не противоречит с EJB (и тем более с JBoss), так что это вообще "не в тему".

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Надо сказать, в вопросе Вы путаете технологии и контейнеры. В частности, Tomcat, JBoss, WebSphere - это сервера приложений. Что касается EJB, Spring и Hibernate, это по сути каркасы для решения различного рода задач.

Сервер Tomcat - это в глобальном смысле веб-сервер, состоящий из ряда компонент (coyote (http-коннектор), jasper(транслятор JSP), catalina(сам servlet-контейнер) и т.п.).

Сервера JBoss и WebSphere - это известные сервера приложений, которые реализут большой набор различных каркасов/спецификаций J2EE. Основная задача данных решений - это реализация каких-либо бизнес-задач. Например, технология EJB имеет реализацию и в JBoss, и WebSphere. В каждом из данных серверов реализация своя.

Каркасы Spring и Hibernate можно использовать на любом из них.